# Does a drop in GDP per capita, with the population staying around the same, mean people on average are poorer?

Tags: gdp, population-economics

Essentially, I'm trying to determine if there is a correlation between a drop in GDP per capita (e.g. during the 2008 financial crisis, Australia's GDP per capita dropped from USD \$49,000 to $42,000 2009) and the average income.

Comment: You make a distinction between "GDP per capita" and "average income". But "GDP per capita" *is* one of many possible measures of "average income". Perhaps you could more clearly specify what you're thinking of when you say "average income"?

Comment: Maybe median income adjusted by purchasing power parity is what you're looking for? It takes into account how much you can actually buy in a country with the money you earn

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the population size, what matters in terms of income is real or nominal terms. The gdp per capita may rise despite a constant population for the economy. But is it real terms that’s what matters. In an environment where the inflation skyrockets, gdp per capita is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes, but mind the fact that GDP per capita is, by definition, an arithmetic mean of a country's income; meaning that it measures directly the average economy's aggregate output per person in the country. 'Average income' can be interpreted in a number of ways, one of which is GDP-per-capita, but another is median income (50th percentile income), which can tell a very different story (particularly around recessions).

At face value, the question seems to answer itself since 'GDP-per-capita' and 'average income' are generally used interchangeably; however there is evidently some nuance here.

I hope I've answered your question.